# AngularJS directive update when binding to model

Tags: angularjs, directive, watch

Currently I am trying to add a login to my angular application. The angular User Session works great with the login and logout. But my directive is a trouble maker.

I added a new HTML attribute tag named `access` that takes a comma seperated list of user roles. The user must have at least one of these roles in order to see the html element. If he has none of the roles, he can not see the element (I hav no idea wether this is the proper way to do this, but I had no other idea in order to hide navigation items from users that have no access).

```
<a class="navbar-brand" ng-href="/serverDebug" access="admin">Server Debug</a>
```

Here only users with the role `admin` can see the menu link.
And a directive should watch over all the elements with the `access` attribute.

```
app.directive('access',
    function (AuthSharedService, UserSession) {
        return {
            /*
                    A = Attribute   = <div Doc></div>
                    C = Class       = <div class="Doc"></div>
                    E = Element     = <Doc data="book_data"></Doc>
                    M = coMment     = <!--directive:Doc -->
             */
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("directive start");
                //scope.$watch('UserSession.user.roles', function (val) {
                    console.log("directive watcher change");
                    var roles = attrs.access.split(',');
                    if (roles.length > 0) {
                        if (AuthSharedService.isAuthorized(roles)) {
                            element.removeClass('hide');
                        } else {
                            element.addClass('hide');
                        }
                    }
                //});
            }
        };
    }
);
```

The function `AuthSharedService.isAuthorized` takes an array of roles and compares them with the UserSession. (In UserSession only the user id, the email and his roles are stored.)
If one of the taken roles is in the user roles, it gives back `true`, otherweise `false`. This function is working great. I am also using it in other places of the application.

But it seems the directive only triggers once at the angular js initial loading at the beginning. At this point, `AuthSharedService.isAuthorized` always says `false` because the UserSession is not loaded yet. But this is automaticly done in the `app.run` section of angular. So just a few nano-seconds later the session is loaded and the user is logged in.
But the directive does not trigger a second time. So I tried to use a watcher in order to trigger the directive every time, the user-roles change (at the beginning there are null, and then it will be an array, so a watcher should work). But it seems that I am not skilled enouphe to do so.

What is my mistake? Is my watcher wrong? Or do I have to use the watcher outside the directive? But then how I call the directive?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a watcher and have it call a function:

```
app.directive('access',
    function (AuthSharedService, UserSession) {
        return {
            /*
                    A = Attribute   = <div Doc></div>
                    C = Class       = <div class="Doc"></div>
                    E = Element     = <Doc data="book_data"></Doc>
                    M = coMment     = <!--directive:Doc -->
             */
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("directive start");
                var roles = attrs.access.split(',');
                function checkAuthorized() {
                    if (!roles.length) return false;
                    return AuthSharedService.isAuthorized(roles);
                }
                scope.$watch(checkAuthorized, function (val) {
                    console.log("directive watcher change ",val);
                    if (val) {
                        element.removeClass('hide');
                    } else {
                        element.addClass('hide');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
);
```

---

> Why can a watcher watch a function? I only use a watcher for variables and models

From the Docs:

> ### `$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality])`
>
> watchExpression
>
> Expression that is evaluated on each `$digest` cycle.
>   A change in the return value triggers a call to the `listener`.
>
> - `function(scope)` called with current scope as a parameter.
> - `string` Evaluated as [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)
>
> [— AngularJS $rootScope/$scope API Reference - `$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: of course, using a inner function. Thank you :)   Just a extendet question: So in this case the function `checkAuthorized` gets called immediately when the directive is created. And the watcher can watch a function that watches over all `access` attributes? Why can a watcher watch a function? I only use a watcher for variables and models...